# Select for multiple fields with "IN" expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Can we optimize this query any further:

I need to get:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 
WHERE (column1, column2) in (SELECT c1, c2 FROM table2);
```

Since the above query is not supported:

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 join (SELECT c1, c2 from table2) as table3 
ON table1.column1 = c1 and table1.column2 = c2
```

---

Edit:
I added table2 for simplicity.
But it is actually

```
select c1, min(c2) from table2 group by c1;
```

Comment: Why not just use EXISTS ?

Comment: Note: changing the question forces us to change the answers, too. I won't. I already added an answer. If you have a new question: ask that as a new question, not by presenting it as an un-simplified version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is NO.
You've already got the best query. A JOIN is usually the fastest option. The missing column alias would result in a syntax error, though.
Fixed and simplified with aliases and the simpler `USING` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 t1
JOIN  (
   SELECT c1 AS column1, min(c2) AS column2
   FROM   table2
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) t2 USING (column1, column2)
```

Key to performance are two [multi-column indices](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) (unique or primary key constraints work, too):

```
CREATE INDEX t1_mult_idx ON table1 (column1, column2);
CREATE INDEX t2_mult_idx ON table2 (c1, c2);
```

You may be interested in [this related question on dba.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51895/efficient-query-to-get-greatest-value-per-group-from-big-table/52015) about difficulties using an index in such a query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (select *
   from table2  ex
   WHERE t1.column1 = ex.c1
     and t1.column2 = ex.c2
   );
```

UPDATE: and here for the MIN(c2) case:

```
SELECT * from table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS (select *
   from table2 ex
   WHERE ex.c1 = t1.column1
     and ex.c2 = t1.column2
   )
AND NOT EXISTS (select *
   from table2 nx
   WHERE nx.c1 = t1.column1
     and nx.c2 < t1.column2
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, isn't just

```
select * from table1 inner join table2 on table1.column1 = table2.c2 and table1.column1 = table2.c2;
```